# UPDATING SQLite databases using variables

Tags: php

I am updating a record of a SQLite database as follows:

```
$db->exec('UPDATE Movies SET name = "new movie" WHERE ID="4"');
```

but instead of using `name` and `ID` I want to use some variables, `$NewItemName` and `$hId`.

Entering the variables as they are won't work. Neither using escape characters like `\"$DbItemName\"` and `\"$hId\"`.

Any idea of the right syntax pls?

Answer (score 0):

Using bind_param

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE Movies SET name = "new movie" WHERE ID="?"');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: try following the example here : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp